# Checking which ArrayAdapter Spinner currently uses

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, custom-arrayadapter

I have four ArrayAdapters that uses 4 different arrays

```
adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,getResources().getStringArray( R.array.array1) );
adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,getResources().getStringArray(R.array. array2));
adapter3 = new  ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,getResources().getStringArray(R.array. array3));
adapter4 = new  ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,getResources().getStringArray(R.array. array4));
```

An i have two spinners

```
spinnerFrom = findViewById(R.id.unit_From_spinner)
spinnertTo = findViewById(R.id.unit_To_spinner);
```

On clicked button , `spinnerFrom` and `spinnertTo` fills  with adapter specified on code.

My main idea was write in project something like this:

```
if (spinnerFrom use adapter 1 or adapter 2 || spinnerTo use adapter 1 or adapter 2){
some code
}
else if (spinnerFrom use adapter 3 or adapter 4 || spinnerTO use adapter 3 or adapter 4){
some code
}
```

Question: How can I get the curently used adapter and specify its name (`adapter1`/`adapter2`/`adapter3`/`adapter4`) by `spinnerFrom` and `spinnertTo`spinners  and make if-else (or should i use `swtich-case`) structure?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple equality check should work:

```
if (spinner.getAdapter() == adapterInstance) //etc
```

Normally, you don't want to do this in Java, since it compares instances instead of values, but in this case, it should do what you need, which is compare instances.